# HUAWEI optical router password change

Tags: router, encryption, passwords, hashing

I have an optical router from Huawei, and I need to change my super user password. In a downloaded config file, I found this line:

```
UserName="ADMIN_USER" Password="HASHED_PASSWORD" UserLevel="0" Enable="1" Salt="SOME_HASH" PassMode="3"/>
```

I know, in principle, how that hash is generated – first MD5 and then SHA256. But I don't know what type of salt it uses. I am new to encryption, so I will be happy for any help.

The problem: If I change the password but do not change the salt, it will generate some weird combination which later doesn't work and I cannot log into the router.

Salt usually goes behind or in front of password – is it also hashed in MD5 and then in SHA256?

Comment: (1) It might help if you told us the exact model of the router. (2) Why do you need to edit the config file?  Are you *sure* that the router doesn’t provide a normal, password-change interface / function?

Comment: Model is HG8546M. it can be changed only via config file. There is also user password for user which can change som thing like wifi password.

But ADMIN permissions user password should be changed because of security

Comment: @DonX did you identify encryption ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try do this:

1. Change your user account password (usually it's root/admin) via web interface.
2. Download your config file and open it via notepad/notebook.
3. Search for `WebUserInfo`, it looks like this:

```
<X_HW_WebUserInfo NumberOfInstances="2">  
<X_HW_WebUserInfoInstance InstanceID="1" UserName="root" Password="password1" UserLevel="1"   
Enable="1" ModifyPasswordFlag="0" Salt="salt1" PassMode="3" Alias="cpe-1"/>
<X_HW_WebUserInfoInstance InstanceID="2" UserName="telecomadmin" Password="password2" UserLevel="0"   
Enable="1" AccessInterface="LAN" ModifyPasswordFlag="0" Salt="salt2" PassMode="3" Alias="cpe-2"/>
```

I used values **password1** and **salt1** for user login and **password2** and **salt2** for superadmin login for better perception and for decreasing size of this code. Usual values will be much longer because of encryption.

4. In p.1. you changed your user account password (there are values **password1** and **salt1** in code above). Now to change superadmin account password you need to copy value **password1** to field with value **password2** and copy value **salt1** to field with value **salt2** (sorry if this explanation is hard-understandable:D).
5. Now save config file and update it via web interface.
6. Try to login your router using **telecomadmin** and value of **password1**.
   P.S. I tried to do this with router HG8245H5 and it worked. And no any encryption/decryption stuff:)
   P.S.S. If you want to change login - you can just change it in config file and it works.